# Zip two types and make object type?

Tags: typescript

Given these two types

```
type keys = ['name', 'age', 'height']
type valueTypes = [string, number, number]
```

How can I create a zipped object type? `{name: string, age: number, height: number}`?

Here's my attempt:

```
type Zip<K, V> = {
    [KK in keyof K]: {
        [VV in keyof V]: K[KK] extends string ? Record<K[KK], V[VV]> : never
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Normally the term "zip" refers to a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)), where you turn an ordered pair (or triplet, etc) of arrays into an array of ordered pairs (or triplets, etc).  See [Python's `zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), [Haskell's `zip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) for examples.

One way to zip tuple types in TypeScript, neglecting the edge cases where the tuples are of differing lengths, is as follows:

```
type ZipTuple<T extends readonly any[], U extends readonly any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [T[K], K extends keyof U ? U[K] : never]
}
```

We're just using the [mapped tuple/array feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) added in TS3.1.

That produces the following:

```
type Keys = ['name', 'age', 'height']
type Values = [string, number, number]

type KVTuple = ZipTuple<Keys, Values>;
// type KVTuple = [["name", string], ["age", number], ["height", number]]
```

Armed with that, we can define `KeyValTuplesToObject<K, V>` which takes a tuple `K` of keys and a same-length tuple `V` of values and produce the object type where each key maps to the corresponding value:

```
type KeyValTuplesToObject<K extends readonly PropertyKey[], V extends readonly any[]> =
  ZipTuple<K, V>[number] extends infer Z ?
  [Z] extends [[any, any]] ? { [P in Z[0]]: Extract<Z, [P, any]>[1] } : never : never
```

That first uses `ZipTuple` to convert the keys and value tuples to a tuple of key-value pairs, indexes into it with `[number]` to get the key-value tuples as a union, and then makes a mapped type that iterates over all the keys in these tuples and extracts the value from the corresponding element.

---

UPDATE for TS4.1; the above `KeyValTuplesToObject` can be simiplified using [key remapping in mapped types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#key-remapping-mapped-types):

```
type KeyValTuplesToObject<K extends readonly PropertyKey[], V extends readonly any[]> =
  { [T in ZipTuple<K, V>[number]as T[0]]: T[1] };
```

---

Using the same `Keys` and `Values` from before, this is the outcome:

```
type KVObject = KeyValTuplesToObject<Keys, Values>
/* type KVObject = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    height: number;
} */
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200919#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oG0DkA7AhgWwgwBooMcBzQkjACwgEtybgMBdAKFEigDUcAbAK4QkqNAmAAnelnIksgvACMIk+YpWSOncNABa9MABVBYfhAA8RqBAAewCFgAmSSRBxOA9ln4goOLBA0VhIAVRt7RxcoNw9vX39A4IA+FCgAb3YodBgoGSgAa3hPADMoI1YALnQjNBgQ2AiHZyQikFKocIB+TrrWKGqsCAA3VQ4AXyydbhgeEzNoVANjU3MLOEQSPiERZIBudgB6Q6guaFn58zS0NAAiXAJbkglpWQa7iggnqAVlMZI7nRGMxvr9NKxtGdYPBtpcREZPAB5JQAKwgAGNgOsmlFXO4vD4-AAFSSeSCSUAbYJbHEtGL4+J+AJBVipZBZDI1PJYKDLOHrLbJNBgsY4JC1AAMEOqtQAjP1xgdpuceMi0Zi0htYat4UjURisRsEFsBMIEMkjgAqU66WCq-Ua1CZbLZB4QaovGTkA4u-yUQYaVQ+l1ApjAAN-SQHcZQS2HdjsIA)

Comment: Instead of iterating over `keyof T` then test if the key is in `keyof U` we can just iterate over `keyof T & keyof U` like this:

 `[K in keyof T & keyof U]: [T[K], U[K]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
type Shift<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => any) extends ((first: any, ...rest: infer R) => any) ? R : never;

type ConvertIntoObject<Keys extends any[], Values extends any[]> = _ConvertIntoObject<Keys, Values, {}>
type _ConvertIntoObject<Keys extends any[], Values extends any[], Acc extends {}> = {
  0: Acc,
  1: _ConvertIntoObject<Shift<Keys>, Shift<Values>, {
    [K in Keys[0]]: Values[0]
  } & Acc>
}[Keys['length'] extends 0 ? 0 : 1];



type a = ["e", "i", "o"]
type b = [1, 2, 3]
type c = ConvertIntoObject<a, b> // type c is { e: 1, i: 2, o: 3}
```

Comment: [Circular conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) of the form you are using are [not currently supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-421354117).  Luckily they are not necessary to answer this question.   Also, please consider adding at least a short explanation.