# Convert from function Parameters type to Object of types

Tags: typescript

TS utility type **Parameters<T>** returns array of types:

```
const f = (a: number, b: boolean) => { 
  //...
}

// [a: number, b: boolean]
type FParams = Parameters<typeof f>;
```

I need to convert it to object of types:

```
[a: number, b: boolean] -> { a: number, b: boolean }
```

I have already seen these questions:

[Typescript - Convert from Array of types to Object of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059424/typescript-convert-from-array-of-types-to-object-of-types)

[Zip two types and make object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926203/zip-two-types-and-make-object-type/58939723#58939723)

None of introduced variants works for me

Comment: those are positional arguments, so their name has no value

Comment: yse, but they got type and we can get all of them as array notation

Comment: It says not possible here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713319/4883195